# Deleting tag element from Rails database when certain tag is no longer used in any post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a simple blog-style Rails app and have successfully added a rather simple #tags function. The problem I'm facing is that I cant think of a way to remove tags that are no longer used in any post. For example, if I make a tag #twitter in the first post, then remove the said post, tag #twitter will remain in my database even though it's not used/referenced anywhere. I would like to remove unused tags. Third DB table is created for relation (post has many tags, tags belong to many posts) and the relation between tag and post is "has_and_belongs_to_many"

```
**tag.rb**
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

```
**post.rb**
belongs_to :user
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, dependent: :destroy


    after_create do
        hashtags = self.body.scan(/#\w+/)
        hashtags.uniq.map do |hashtag|
            tag = Tag.find_or_create_by(name: hashtag.downcase.delete('#'))
            self.tags << tag
        end
    end

    before_update do 
        self.tags.clear 
        hashtags = self.body.scan (/#\w+/)
        hashtags.uniq.map do |hashtag|
            tag = Tag.find_or_create_by(name: hashtag.downcase.delete('#'))
            self.tags << tag
        end
    end
```

```
from **post_controller.rb**
 def hashtags 
    tag = Tag.find_by(name: params[:name])
    @posts = tag.posts.page(params[:page])
  end
```

```
**schema.rb**
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "image_filename"
    t.string "posts"
    t.string "image"
  end

  create_table "posts_tags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.bigint "tag_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_posts_tags_on_post_id"
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_posts_tags_on_tag_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: Check if any tag in the deleted post no longer has references and delete if not. Not a terribly useful operation, IMO; in general you'd want to try to normalize and suggest tags, meaning you'd want your tag history corpus available anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I created tagging was to create a `Tag` model and table, and then a `Taggings` model and table.

tag.rb

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, through: :taggings

end
```

tagging.rb

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

So now you just have the join table that uses a post_id and tag_id to join the two. This way you can enforce `uniq` on your tag table to avoid redundant tags. As mentioned above you could build an `after_destroy` method that deletes a tag after checking to see if it is used anywhere else. Or like Dave Newton mentioned keep it around for historic purposes for autocomplete suggestions.